# Build sql query from multiple tables for cyfe dashboard

Tags: mysql, sql

For the purpose of monitoring my data from my users I want to visualise my data in a Cohort analysis. Lets say that i have the following tables in my database:

Table: track_register

**user_id, date, time**

And in the following table:

Table: track_login
**user_id, date, time, succes**

How i want my cohort analysis to look is like:

Months   Sign Ups   loged in more then once
May              40                         80%

I am using Cyfe to visualise this so the data has to be formatted in a table like this:
Month,Sign Ups,Loged in more then once
May 2015,40,32
Jun 2015,60,55

([click here](http://www.cyfe.com/custom) for cyfe example)

Eventually i want to add more data to the cohort from other tables such as percentage of users who actually bought the product and more of that good stuff.

The first set of data (the signups per month) is not the hard part. But what i am struggling with is how to fetch the data from the track login table. I will have to count the number of times a specific user has loged in and if thats > 1 then +1. I can imagine that u use CASE for that. The trouble is to separated it by the correct moth. Because the moth where de +1 supposed to go needs to be fetched from the track_register table.

Its seems kind of hard to me to put this all in one single query? But if it couldn't be done why go to the trouble of building a cohort analysis on cyfe?

Comment: MySQL and MS SQL Server are two different products. Don't tag products not involved...

Answer (score 0):

Hi DATE as field name is restricted so I used DATA.

You can try this code:

```
    SELECT   TO_CHAR(NVL(a.data, b.data), 'MON YYYY') months
         , COUNT(DISTINCT a.login) sign_ups
         , SUM(CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT b.login) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Loged_in_more_then_once
    FROM   track_register a LEFT JOIN track_login b ON a.login = b.login
GROUP BY   TO_CHAR(NVL(a.data, b.data), 'MON YYYY')
ORDER BY   1
```

Or:

```
     SELECT   TO_CHAR(NVL(a.data, b.data), 'MON YYYY') months
         , COUNT(DISTINCT a.login) sign_ups
         , SUM(CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT b.login) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Loged_in_more_then_once
    FROM   track_register a LEFT JOIN track_login b
              ON a.login = b.login AND LAST_DAY(a.data) = LAST_DAY(b.data)
GROUP BY   TO_CHAR(NVL(a.data, b.data), 'MON YYYY')
ORDER BY   1
```

Comment: Ok thanks! i will try this. If date is restricted why can i enter it as a collum name in mysql?

Comment: When i test it in Myphpadmin I get errors that TO_CHAR isn't recognized. I can fetch the date data another way but whats my biggest problem is that i Cant use COUNT within the WHEN statement. It gives error  #1111 - Invalid use of group function